# Slick Slider autoplay stops when touched on mobile/tablet

Tags: javascript, android, ios, slick.js

I have an issue I was hoping someone could help me with.

It's regarding
[Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

I have a slider set to autoplay, and both pauseOnHover and pauseOnFocus set to false.

Here is my code:

```
$('.cc-slider-container').slick({
infinite: true,
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
autoplay:true,
autoplaySpeed:5000,
pauseOnHover:false,
pauseOnFocus:false
});
```

This works as expected on desktop with autoplay even if its hovered. However on mobile (android) and ipad when I touch the slider to scroll the page the autoplay stops and never resumes.

anyone have any advice?

I am using slick version 1.8.0,

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I use 'slickPlay' method to restart autoplay function, like this:

```
$('.cc-slider-container').on('touchstart', e => {
  $('.cc-slider-container').slick('slickPlay');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it saves me time

Comment: Very nice. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and the way I fixed it was to add:

```
.cc-slider-container { pointer-events: none; }
```

to the css.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Zyra, I had thought about that but unfortunately adding 'pointer-events: none;' disables interaction with the slider - i.e. can't touch to move it to next slide. Thanks for suggesting it though. It's frustrating :-(